# Two meanings of "Someone believes everyone to be invited"

Tags: syntax, semantics, meaning, quantifiers, scope

Carnie claims in his syntax book that the sentence

> Someone believes everyone to be invited

has two meanings. I can see only one (when the existential quantifier has scope over universal one: when there is a person who believes that everyone was invited). How to see the meaning when the universal quantifier takes scope over the existential one?

Comment: (1) there is a given person who believes that everybody is invited (2) it is true of everybody that there is someone (not necessarily the same person) who believes them to be invited.

Comment: @JD2000 what about the usage of "to be X" used frequently in news articles indicating that something is going to happen? That would give this a third meaning